401 Unauthorized - authentication token not provided, GitHub npm
I have to download a package from my-org with GitHub actions for Node projects.
I have an action like this to make an .npmrc file:
> ${{ inputs.npmrc_path }}
echo "@my-org:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/" >> ${{ inputs.npmrc_path }}
if [ ! -z "${{ inputs.github_token }}" ]; then
    echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${{ inputs.github_token }}" >> ${{ inputs.npmrc_path }}
    echo "@my-org:always-auth=true" >> ${{ inputs.npmrc_path }}
fi
echo "registry=https://registry.npmjs.org" >> ${{ inputs.npmrc_path }}
if [ ! -z "${{ inputs.nexus_url }}" ]; then
    auth=$(echo -n '${{ inputs.nexus_user }}:${{ inputs.nexus_password }}' | base64)
    echo "${{ inputs.nexus_url }}:_auth=$auth" >> ${{ inputs.npmrc_path }}
    echo "always-auth=true" >> ${{ inputs.npmrc_path }}
fi

when it's called by another action, token with all permissions is provided, I have admin permissions in that package and the repo which is calling the action has access to the package, but it gives me the following failure:
npm error code E401
npm error 401 Unauthorized - GET https://npm.pkg.github.com/@my-org%2fpackage - authentication token not provided
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/runner/.npm/_logs/...log

package.json has this:
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "@my-org/package": "0.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.17.0"
  }
}


In local I can download.

I understood that the action can not pull a package when called by another action. The calling action is triggering a workflow dispatch event and passing a token.

Does the token have packages:readz scope (if it is a PAT token)?
Is this a default GITHUB_TOKEN from the calling repo - this token does not have permissions outside of the calling repo even if it can pull a package when used in its own repo.


i use a token with all scope and i overwrite github_token with it in the call

There is no token on the url in the error message. For some reason the token is not set.  Is it possible that this line echo "${{ inputs.nexus_url }}:_auth=$auth" >> ${{ inputs.npmrc_path }} overrides the line where the token is added?
